# HTML5 session storage not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am using session storage to grab my access token generated on the end of my URL by Instagram when a user has authenticated. This isn't working for me on my localhost, please look at the pen I have created as an example of the output. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eHGBf#access_token=12345.67890

Here is the code I am using:

```
var token = window.location.hash.substr(1).split("=");
var storeToken = token[1];

if (typeof(Storage) != 'undefined') {
    sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', storeToken);
    document.getElementById('access_token').innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken');
} else {
    document.getElementById('access_token').innerHTML = 'Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage';
}
```

and to display the access token:

```
<div id="access_token"></div>
```

When I refresh the page on my localhost (without the access token in the URL) or navigate to other pages and back to the homepage where the token has been displayed in the ID, it returns 'undefined' and I have to log in again. I thought it should have saved the token?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is working for me. What is your desired output?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. When I refresh the page on my localhost (without the access token in the URL) or navigate to other pages and back to the homepage where the token has been displayed in the ID, it returns 'undefined' and I have to log in again. I thought it should have saved the token?

Comment: Well, it does save the token, but make sure you don't rewrite it (eg. include the javascript above on a page where you don't want to save a new token). Otherwise you could check if `storeToken`is defined, if not get it from `sessionStorage`.

Comment: I posted, then deleted an answer suggesting using localStorage, deleted because I'm not sure I know what I'm talking about.  I *am* curious whether using localStorage solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var token = window.location.hash.substr(1).split("=");
    var storeToken = token[1];

    if (storeToken) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', storeToken);
    }

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')) { 
        document.getElementById('access_token').innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken'); 
    }
```